# When exporting Excel to PDF, transform multiple URLs in one cell into multiple hyperlinks

Tags: excel, pdf

I have seen a lot of answers about creating URLs when exporting from Excel to PDF, but in my case I don't have ONE URL in each cell, I can have MULTIPLE URLs in one cell ! (But they are only text, since Excel can't support 2 clickable links in one cell).

I have a document with multiple cells which each contains multiple links inside.
For example, a cell could contain :

```
[http://google.com
http://facebook.com]
```

(The brackets are not in the cell, and there is a new line character (alt+enter) between the links.)

These links are not clickable in Excel, because it is not possible to have 2 clickable links in one cell in Excel.
I want to export the cells to PDF with a macro (using Range(...).ExportAsFixedFormat), and I would like those links to become clickable.

Is there a way to make those links clickable in the PDF created, since they are a text URL ?
(For example, is there an option when I export to say "if you see a string which look like a URL, make it clickable" ?)

I appreciate if you know how to solve this.
Let me know if I can give you more information.

Comment: `ExportAsFixedFormat` doesn't have any option like this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if I could use a workaround to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of any workaround from Excel.